# GDB Disassemble: Print only raw binary data (using column and awk)

Tags: text-processing, awk, gdb

I'm trying to get only the raw binary data from the `gdb` disassemble output.
My current output is the following:

```
$ gdb -batch -ex "disassemble/r btif_set_adapter_property" libbluetooth_qti.so | column -ts $'\t'
Dump of assembler code for function _Z25btif_set_adapter_propertyPK13bt_property_t:
   0x0011e8c1 <+0>:                                                                  e9 f0 41 c8 b0                 jmp    0xb0da2ab6
   0x0011e8c6 <+5>:                                                                  04 46                          add    $0x46,%al
   0x0011e8c8 <+7>:                                                                  67 48                          addr16 dec %eax
   0x0011e8ca <+9>:                                                                  c0 ef 50                       shr    $0x50,%bh
   0x0011e8cd <+12>:                                                                 00 00                          add    %al,(%eax)
   0x0011e8cf <+14>:                                                                 21 78 44                       and    %edi,0x44(%eax)
   0x0011e8d2 <+17>:                                                                 07                             pop    %es
   0x0011e8d3 <+18>:                                                                 68 38 68 47 90                 push   $0x90476838
   0x0011e8d8 <+23>:                                                                 02 a8 40 f9 cd 0a              add    0xacdf940(%eax),%ch
   0x0011e8de <+29>:                                                                 01 60 08                       add    %esp,0x8(%eax)
   0x0011e8e1 <+32>:                                                                 a8 f9                          test   $0xf9,%al
   0x0011e8e3 <+34>:                                                                 21 51 f1                       and    %edx,-0xf(%ecx)
   0x0011e8e6 <+37>:                                                                 62                             (bad)  
   0x0011e8e7 <+38>:                                                                 ea 60 48 d4 e9 00 23           ljmp   $0x2300,$0xe9d44860
```

The strange thing is, that it still doesn't delimit the columns by tabs but by whitespaces which looks like tabs. So I'm unable to use `| awk '{print $2}'` here.

Next problem is that the raw binary data has different length and columns 2..8 might contain the raw binary data I need.

Maybe I'm thinking too complicated and there is a built-in way in `gdb` but wasn't able to find any.

So the output I want is this (everything in one line):

```
e9 f0 41 c8 b0 04 46 67 48 c0 ef 50 00 00 21 78 44 07 68 38 68 47 90 02 a8 40 f9 cd 0a 01 60 08 a8 f9 21 51 f1 62 ea 60 48 d4 e9 00 23
```

EDIT: Output of `gdb` itself:

```
$ gdb -batch -ex "disassemble/r btif_set_adapter_property" libbluetooth_qti.so
Dump of assembler code for function _Z25btif_set_adapter_propertyPK13bt_property_t:
   0x0011e8c1 <+0>: e9 f0 41 c8 b0  jmp    0xb0da2ab6
   0x0011e8c6 <+5>: 04 46   add    $0x46,%al
   0x0011e8c8 <+7>: 67 48   addr16 dec %eax
   0x0011e8ca <+9>: c0 ef 50    shr    $0x50,%bh
   0x0011e8cd <+12>:    00 00   add    %al,(%eax)
   0x0011e8cf <+14>:    21 78 44    and    %edi,0x44(%eax)
   0x0011e8d2 <+17>:    07  pop    %es
   0x0011e8d3 <+18>:    68 38 68 47 90  push   $0x90476838
   0x0011e8d8 <+23>:    02 a8 40 f9 cd 0a   add    0xacdf940(%eax),%ch
   0x0011e8de <+29>:    01 60 08    add    %esp,0x8(%eax)
   0x0011e8e1 <+32>:    a8 f9   test   $0xf9,%al
   0x0011e8e3 <+34>:    21 51 f1    and    %edx,-0xf(%ecx)
   0x0011e8e6 <+37>:    62  (bad)  
   0x0011e8e7 <+38>:    ea 60 48 d4 e9 00 23    ljmp   $0x2300,$0xe9d44860
```

Comment: I'm confused: firs you want disassembly, then you want a hexdump of the file; which one is it?

Comment: a disassembly / binary analysis tool might be better suited to printing contents of functions (if they persist through compilation, optimization, link-time optimization and linking) than a debugger like `gdb`: Have you considered `radare2`?

Comment: `column -ts $'\t'` doesn't tell column to produce tab-separated output, it tells it to read tab-separated input and produce blanks-separated output. Since it's not doing what you want there's no point it being in the pipeline - show us the raw output of `gdb -batch -ex "disassemble/r btif_set_adapter_property" libbluetooth_qti.so` we can help you create an awk script to post-process **that**.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I want to disassemble a single function and just get the raw binary hexdump. It's a pre-compiled shared lib. There is no compilation on my side. But I'll have a look into radare2. Thx.

Comment: @EdMorton I've updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be lucky with piping the GDB output through the following `awk` program:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^[a-f0-9]{2}$/) printf("%s%s",$i,OFS)} END{print ""}'
```

This will check all "words" (space-separated chunks of text) of the incoming lines of GDB output and check if they are two-digit hex numbers. If so, it will print them. If not, it will do nothing. The printed hex numbers thus found will be separated by the output field separator `OFS`, a space by default. A newline is only printed at end-of-input (the `print` statement automatically appends the "output record separator", by default a newline, so printing "nothing" is equivalent to outputting a newline), so all these hex numbers will appear in one large space-separated stream.

It worked for the example GDB output you provided, but beware that if there are "stray" two-digit hex numbers elsewhere, they will also end up in the output.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your fields are separated by a colon or blank followed by additional blanks so just set FS accordingly:

```
$ awk -F'[: ] +' 'NR>1{o=(o=="" ? "" : o OFS) $3} END{print o}' file
e9 f0 41 c8 b0 04 46 67 48 c0 ef 50 00 00 21 78 44 07 68 38 68 47 90 02 a8 40 f9 cd 0a 01 60 08 a8 f9 21 51 f1 62 ea 60 48 d4 e9 00 23
```

Answer (score 0):

We can extract the info using GNU grep  having PCRE regexes support and then postprocess them using other Linux utilities.
file is the output of gdb command saved to a file.

```
< file \
grep -Po ':\s*((\s\S+)+)\s{2}' |
paste -s - | tr -s '\t :' ' '  |
sed -E 's/^ | $//g'
```

---

Perl can extract them for you:

```
perl -ne '
  print(($"x!!$a++),$1) if /:\s+(\S.*?\S)\s{2}/;
  }{printf $/;
' file
```

Output:

```
e9 f0 41 c8 b0 04 46 67 48 c0 ef 50 00 00 21 78 44 07 68 38 68 47 90 02 a8 40 f9 cd 0a 01 60 08 a8 f9 21 51 f1 62 ea 60 48 d4 e9 00 23
```

---

```
python3 -c 'import sys
ifile = sys.argv[1]
L = []
with open(ifile) as fh:
  for l in fh:
    ln = l.rstrip()
    if ln.find(":") < 0: continue
    f1 = ln.split(":",1)[1].lstrip()
    L += f1[0:f1.find("  ")].split()
print(*L)
' file
```

---

GNU sed stream editor in extended regex mode turned ON:

```
sed -En '
  s/:\s*((\s[[:xdigit:]]{2})+)\s{2}/\n\1\n/;T
  s/.*\n\s(.*)\n.*/\1/;H
  $!d;g;s/.//;s/\s+/ /gp
' file
```